# Copy selected text from RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have searched around on the net but I cannot find a method of copying/cutting/pasting selected text from a `RichTextBox`.

Even MSDN does not have an answer. The code they provide does not work: `Copy()` only appears to work on TextBoxes, not RichTextBoxes.

Comment: Which RichTextBox are you talking about ? Windows Forms or WPF ?

Comment: What example does not work? Link please!

Comment: Its a C# Windows Form application. The copy() function is on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.copy.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.0 and above you can always use [Clipboard.SetText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.settext.aspx)

I found it useful to use the Clipboard when I want everything in the richTextBox without having to select everything first or when I need to change the string:

```
string text = "Summary:" + Environment.NewLine + this.richTextBoxSummary.Text;
Clipboard.SetText(text);
```

Answer (score 13):

if I copy this method:

```
Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.SelectedRtf, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
```

i can't paste to notepad

if I copy this method:

```
Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.SelectedText, TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
```

it's working in Word and notepad, but inserts in word without formating

```
richTextBox1.Copy();
```

working in Word and notepad, but I can't modify string value.

How can I copy normally formatted string in Clipboard?

P.S. I found

```
DataObject dto = new DataObject();
dto.SetText(mesrtf, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
dto.SetText(mes, TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dto);
```

it works

Comment: For me, the second argument `true` was necessary. `Clipboard.SetDataObject(dto, true);`

Answer (score 2):

```
richTextBox1.SelectAll();

richTextBox1.Copy();
```

Selects all the text in the box and preserves formatting when you paste it again into notepad

Answer (score 2):

> VB.NET code (Support both formatted and plain text)

Cut

```
 Private Sub CutToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CutToolStripMenuItem.Click

        Try
            If RichTextBox1.SelectedText <> "" Then
                Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf,RichTextBox1.SelectedRtf)
                RichTextBox1.SelectedRtf = ""
            Else
                MsgBox("No item is selected to cut", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Cut")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Can't cut the selected item", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Cut")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Copy

```
 Private Sub CopyToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CopyToolStripMenuItem.Click

        Try
            If RichTextBox1.SelectedText <> "" Then
                Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf,RichTextBox1.SelectedRtf)
            Else
                MsgBox("No item is selected to copy", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Copy")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Can't copy the selected item", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Copy")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Paste

```
 Private Sub PasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PasteToolStripMenuItem.Click

        Try
            If Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Rtf) Then
                RichTextBox1.SelectedRtf = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Rtf).ToString()
            ElseIf Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Text) Then
                RichTextBox1.SelectedText = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString()
            Else
                MsgBox("Clipboard is not contained with the valid text format ", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Paste")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Can't paste the item", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Paste")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Question tagged in `C#` Not `VisualBasic`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Copy

```
Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.Text);
```

Paste

```
richTextBox1.Paste();
```

Cut

```
richTextBox1.Cut();
```

**and there we go I made it simple because its the users choice if he/she wants to copy, paste, Cut a text so just leave it simple no arguments or what so ever LOL the user will be like JUST LET ME COPY A TEXT and that's all**

Answer (score -2):

in wpf just

```
richTextBox1.Copy();

richTextBox1.Paste();
```

Comment: This question is tagged WinForms, not WPF.