# RichTextBox does not copy new lines to the clipboard

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

In the code, I generate formatted text into a WPF RichTextBox. I use Environment.NewLine to insert line break. Everything looks fine. However, when I copy the contents of a RichTextBox to Clipboard (using RichTextBox context menu) and paste it into Word or WordPad, line breaks disappear. However, if I paste the contents of the clipboard as plain text (e.g. into notepad), the new lines do not disappear. Don't know why this is so?

Update:

```cs
// _richTextBox is my object RichTextBox
var doc = _richTextBox.Document;
var paragraph = doc.Blocks.FirstOrDefault() as Paragraph;
if (paragraph == null) return;

var span = new Span();
span.Inlines.Add(new Underline(new Run($"Header: {Environment.NewLine}")));
span.Inlines.Add(new Run("Text content"));

paragraph.Inlines.Add(span);
```

Comment: Not sure, but is it because of `\r\n` vs `\n` issue? As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-6.0, for Windows it's `\r\n`, for Unix it's `\n`.

Comment: Maybe you can provide some code. Also, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624392/4688321.

Comment: Environment.NewLine inserts on my OS (Win 10) `\r\n`, which should be correct.

Comment: @kiner_shah I added code for you. I also looked at the recommended post. Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem. I'd like to know why the native RichTextBox copy-to-clipboard function doesn't insert line breaks when pasted into a Word document.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a [mre] as there are some parts missing e.g. what is `doc`? Where are you copying to clipboard, etc?

Comment: @kiner_shah I am sorry . What is doc I added. As I already wrote, I copy to the clipboard using the control's native functions - I select the mouse text in the control or use Ctr+A, then mouse right-click and select Copy from the context menu. Is this sufficient or is some information still missing?

Comment: I found a link (may not solve your issue but worth reading): https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966530/4688321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple in the end. I didn't notice that there was a `LineBreak` object. If you use `LineBreak` instead of `\r\n` (`Environment.NewLine`), then line break will work in both plain text and formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with RichTextBox which client must be copy-paste with **Word** application. To my surprise, the `Environment.NewLine` did not work. You have to insert `paragraph.Inlines.Add( new LineBreak( ) );`

Here is complete summary when copy paste from RichTextBox to each application:

[image]

1. The wrong-est `\n` not working in any application, unless it is newline aware such as *Notepad++*

   ```
        var doc = m_RichTextBox.Document;
        doc.Blocks.Clear( );
        var p = new Paragraph( );
        doc.Blocks.Add( p );

        p.Inlines.Add( new Run( "Line1\n" ) );
        p.Inlines.Add( new Run( "Line2\n" ) );
        p.Inlines.Add( new Run( "Line3\n" ) );
   ```
2. The `Environment.NewLine`
   Notepad says ok, but Word still decided to protest.

   ```
        /* Same setup code omitted .... */
        p.Inlines.Add( new Run( "Line1" + Environment.NewLine ) );
        p.Inlines.Add( new Run( "Line2" + Environment.NewLine ) );
        p.Inlines.Add( new Run( "Line3" + Environment.NewLine ) );
   ```
3. The correct one

   ```
        /* Same setup code omitted .... */
        p.Inlines.Add( new Run( "Line1" ) );
        p.Inlines.Add( new LineBreak( ) );
        p.Inlines.Add( new Run( "Line2" ) );
        p.Inlines.Add( new LineBreak( ) );
        p.Inlines.Add( new Run( "Line3" ) );
        p.Inlines.Add( new LineBreak( ) );
   ```